# How to go from a spark.LinearGradient to beginGradientFill

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I'm trying to translate this LinearGradient

```
<s:LinearGradient rotation="90" scaleX="44.2931" x="10.294" y="-0.276" >
    <s:GradientEntry color="#FFD500" ratio="0"/>
    <s:GradientEntry color="#F5A106" ratio="1"/>
</s:LinearGradient>
```

into an equivalent beginGradientFill call. My best guess of the translation is this

```
var matr:Matrix = new Matrix();
matr.createGradientBox(20, 20, Math.PI/2, 10.294, -0.276);
g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xFFD500, 0xF5A106], [1,1], [0,1], matr);
```

but I'm not sure if this is right, nor I know what the size of the box should be (the two 20s in the code above are just me trying stuff). Would love any expert expert opinions!

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sample can illustrate how to draw the same fill as in `s:LinearGradient`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application creationComplete="init()" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public static const GRADIENT_DIMENSION:Number = 1638.4;

        private static const GRADIENT_SCALE_X:Number = 44.2931;
        private static const GRADIENT_X:Number = 10.294;
        private static const GRADIENT_Y:Number = 0.276;
        private static const ROTATION_DEGREES:Number = 90;

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var g:Graphics = drawingTarget.graphics;
            g.clear();
            var matrix:Matrix = getMatrix(ROTATION_DEGREES, GRADIENT_X, -GRADIENT_Y, GRADIENT_SCALE_X);
            g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [ 0xFFD500, 0xF5A106 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 0, 255 ], matrix);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, drawingTarget.width, drawingTarget.height);
            g.endFill();
        }

        private function getMatrix(rotationDegrees:Number, x:Number, y:Number, scaleX:Number = 1):Matrix
        {
            var commonMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
            commonMatrix.translate(GRADIENT_DIMENSION / 2, GRADIENT_DIMENSION / 2);
            commonMatrix.scale(1 / GRADIENT_DIMENSION, 1 / GRADIENT_DIMENSION);
            var compoundTransform:Matrix = new Matrix();
            compoundTransform.scale(scaleX, 1);
            compoundTransform.rotate(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
            compoundTransform.translate(x, y);
            commonMatrix.concat(compoundTransform);
            return commonMatrix;
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Rect height="50%" width="50%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="{ROTATION_DEGREES}" scaleX="{GRADIENT_SCALE_X}" x="{GRADIENT_X}"
                y="{GRADIENT_Y}">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#FFD500" ratio="0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="#F5A106" ratio="1" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <mx:UIComponent height="50%" id="drawingTarget" width="50%" />
</s:Application>
```

Take a look at `getMatrix()` method which performs all the calculations.

Comment: wait... out of curiosity where did you get the 1638.4 magic number?

Comment: :) Don't you think I'm so smart to get it from my head? :) I've just reverse engineering LinearGradient class :) So all the questions should be asked to Adobe engineers :)